# Amazon SP-APIの利用に必要なLWA認証情報をアプリ側で自動更新する方法はありますか？

Tags: amazon, amazon-selling-partner-api

いつもAmazonセラーセントラルの「デベロッパーセントラル」で、該当アプリのLWA認証情報を手動ローテーションしてアプリに再設定しているのですが、その手間をプログラムで自動化する方法があれば教えてください。
具体的なコードでなくても、それが可能なドキュメントやGithubをご存知でしたら、ご教示ください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

公式ドキュメントには Application Management API (Selling Partner API for Application Management) を使う方法が紹介されています。

- [Rotating your application's LWA credentials](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/rotating-your-apps-lwa-credentials)
- [Application Management API v2023-11-30 Use Case Guide](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/application-management-api-v2023-11-30-use-case-guide)

Comment: 教えていただいた公式ドキュメントのこの項目、どうも読み飛ばしていたみたいです。気づかせていただいてありがとうございました。